# How to recover discarded contacts?

Tags: phone-app

I was trying to save a number using the basic android dialer first I dialed in the number then I gave a name but then I ended up discarding the saving process, now I am unable to recover the number which I was trying to save.
I tried opening up the contacts database which is saved under `/data/data/com.android.providers` but I am unable to retrieve anything from there. Can anyone please suggest on how to find the lost contact?

Comment: If you dialed this number you can find it in your call log.

Comment: I dialed but did not call... Directly selected add to contacts

Comment: Then it wasn't saved anywhere: you didn't call, so no call-log – and you didn't save, so no contact created. Nothing stored, nothing to recover. Bad luck, sorry.

Comment: What about caching? Does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Anything you entered without saving it was never committed to long-term storage, whether as cache or otherwise; it was only in RAM.  There is no way to retrieve this data.